# Vim: Open blank files in insert mode

Tags: vim

Is there a .vimrc command for opening blank files in insert mode? Non blank files would still open in command mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try an `autocommand`:

```
au BufNewFile * startinsert
```

So, with:

```
vim oldfile
```

will enter in `normal` mode, but with:

```
vim newfile
```

will enter in `insert` mode.

Note that

```
vim
```

without files will be in `normal` mode too. Perhaps you would need an additional `autocommand` for it. (**EDIT**: See commments for a [Ben's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1390430/ben) solution to this one)

Comment: For the startup buffer, you can detect that something like: `autocmd VimEnter * if empty(expand("%")) | startinsert | endif`

Comment: `au BufNewFile * startinsert` works perfectly for opening new files into insert mode! Thanks! I'm not sure what @Ben 's code is supposed to do though. Open existing files with no content in insert mode? If so it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @greg: **Ben's** code opens `vim` in insert mode without any file. It works for me. And you can rename the buffer when you save it, like: `:w filename`

Answer (score 0):

To enter insert mode only on **empty** new buffers:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * if wordcount()['chars'] == 0 | startinsert | endif
```

To do that only when opening vim:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if wordcount()['chars'] == 0 | startinsert | endif
```